# Proper way of saving and loading pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I am making a small app where the user can create a game profile, input some data and a picture that can be taken with the camera.

I save most of that profile data with the help of `NSUserDefaults`, but a friend discouraged me from saving the profile image in `NSUserDefault`.

What's the **proper** way to **save and retrieve** images locally in my app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should save it in **`Documents`** or **`Cache`** folder. Here is how to do it.

**Saving** into `Documents` folder:

```
NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/myImage.png"];

BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path 
          contents:nil attributes:nil];

if (!ok) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
} 
else 
{
    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
   [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage)];
   [myFileHandle closeFile];
}
```

**Loading** from `Documents` folder:

```
NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
```

You can also use **`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`** to save your `UIImage` as a `JPEG` file. What's more if you want to save it in `Cache` directory, use:

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches/"]
```

Comment: Do not use `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:...]`. Use `[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(..., NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]` with `NSDocumentDirectory` or `NSCachesDirectory`.

Comment: Why one should not use `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:...]`? Can you explain it?

Comment: I ended up using [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:...] , using Anomie's version gave me errors. I still don't know why I shouldn't according to Anomie.

Comment: @José and Rafal: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is better because it will not break if Apple decides to change their directory structure. In general, the less you have to hard-code, the better. If a specific API function exists for what you want to do, use it. A clean way to get this path would be: `NSString *dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *path = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dir, @"myImage.png", nil]];` (too bad it's so verbose though!)

Comment: oops, just found a nicer way to express the second statement of my example: `NSString *path = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"];`

Comment: Why use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` ? Isn't easier (and faster ?) to directly use `imageData = [[NSData] initWithContentsOfURL: url]` and then `[imageData writeToFile:filePath]` ?

Comment: Too many NSHomeDirectory() calls will cause lots of memory Allocations. You may call NSHomeDirectory() at the time of app launch and keep the path in shared variable. And wherever you need the path, use your shared variable value. It will reduce the memory allocations.

Comment: @Ansari, can you please provide me with a link to documentation that states this. I checked everything I could find about `NSHomeDirectory` and it does not say anything about issue you are writing about. It would be strange if calling this function would cause memory allocations spike.

Comment: @reecon Indeed you wouldn't find everything written in documentations. And the statement I making are based on some profiling results (using Xcode Instruments). Also I not saying it will take a lot of memory when called once or twice or a bit more, but, let say, try calling it for every time your tableview cell loads. It will eventually show some allocation spikes. In my case it was reaching up to 300 Mb, which I have managed to reduce to few Kb.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is use the application's document directory. This is specific to a application and will not be visible to other applications.
How to create this:
Just add a static function to App Delegate and use the function  where ever the path is required.

```
- (NSString )applicationDocumentDirectory {
    /
     Returns the path to the application's documents directory.
     */ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Hope it Helped..

Answer (score 1):

I think [this("iphone-user-defaults-and-uiimages")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625215/iphone-user-defaults-and-uiimages) post addresses your issue. Don't save blobs to a property list such as NSUserDefaults. In your case I would write to disk directly instead.